# angular unit tests failing at evaluating '$browser.$$checkUrlChange()

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

My angular js unit tests appear to fail whenever i try to use

```
scope.$digest();
```

Or

```
$httpBackend.flush();
```

The tests fail and flag the following error -

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$browser.$$checkUrlChange()')

The two dont appear to be related in anyway, one propagates the asynchronous execution of backend api calls and the other re-evaluates the scope model.

I have tried executing my tests using both phantomjs and chrome browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jasmine test fails with undefined is not a function(evaluating $browser.$$checkUrlChange())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785149/jasmine-test-fails-with-undefined-is-not-a-functionevaluating-browser-checku)

Comment: Looks like your angular mocks needs an update

Comment: Yes just stumbled across this, upgrade of angular mocks fixed the problem. thanks!

Comment: You could use voting system to give a thumbs up for that answer then..? :)

Comment: Done! That post was originally hard to find.